# Displaying User Avatar (without duplicates) for each post in a Collection List with Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, devise, ruby-on-rails-5, has-many-through

all,

I want to display a list of collections with many posts.

So I call all collections in the controller as:

```
  def index
    @collections = Collection.order("RANDOM()")
  end
```

Then in the View:

```
   <% @collections.each do |collection| %>

      <%= link_to collection.title, collection %>(<%= collection.posts.count %>)


      <!-- Designers (Users) -->
      <% collection.posts.each do |post_designer| %>
          <!-- I want to display designer avatars in here, I have designer_id from the post, but how do I access Designer table to pull avatar? -->
          <%= post_designer.designer_id %>
      <% end %>

      <!-- Images -->
      <% collection.posts.each do |post| %>
        <%= link_to image_tag(post.image.thumb.url.to_s, class: "fr"), collection %>
      <% end %>

   <% end %>
```

**My question is that:**

I want to display designer avatars in here instead of designer_id, I have designer_id from the post, but how do I access Designer table to pull avatar?

Thank you!!!!

---

**Relations:**

models/collection.rb

```
class Collection < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :designer
  has_many :collectivizations
  has_many :posts, through: :collectivizations
end
```

models/collectivization.rb

```
class Collectivization < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :post
    belongs_to :collection
end
```

models/post.rb

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :designer
  has_many :collectivizations
  has_many :collections, through: :collectivizations
```

### ---------------

**SOLUTION**

It looks like I just an obvious typo error! ‍♂️ The code below works, but it gives dublicates if there is more than 1 post for an user. How can I fix the duplicates?

```
   <% collection.posts.each do |post_designer| %>
      <%= link_to image_tag(post_designer.designer.avatar.url.to_s, class: "avatar-small ml1"), post_designer, class: "fl" %>
    <% end %>
```

[image]

Comment: It seems you have proper relations defined in models. What is the problem with replacing `post_designer.designer_id` with `post_designer.designer`?

Comment: @nattfodd  yes yes I found a stupid typo issue ‍♂️, pulling avatars works but now I have duplicated avatars when there is more multiple posts from a user in the collection. I updated my question. any idea how to get rid of duplicates? Thank you

Comment: Rename the question title, this title and body text are confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try change your code like below. It will fetch first post for designer and you won't see any duplicates for designer.

```
<% collection.posts.select("DISTINCT ON (designer_id) *").each do |post_designer| %>
  <%= link_to image_tag(post_designer.designer.avatar.url.to_s, class: "avatar-small ml1"), post_designer, class: "fl" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: YES DISTINCT! That shit is confusing as hell, I gotta practise that. Thank you!